# php multidimensional array combinations for an ecommerce

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, combinations

I have two tables in mysql: atributes and options.

Atributes

```
Id
Atribute
```

Options

```
Id
Idtribute
Option
```

Example atributes:

```
1, Size
2, Color
3, other
4, n...
```

Example options:

```
1, 1, S
2, 1, L
3, 1, M
4, 2, Red
5, 2, Green
6, 3, One
7, 3, Two
8, 3, Three
9, n, m
```

I want an string output like that:

```
S, Red, One
S, Red, Two
S, Red, Three
S, Green, One
S, Green, two
S, Green, three
L, Red, One
L, Red, Two
L, Red, Three
L, Green, One
S, Green, two
S, Green, three
etc.
```

I have tried with recursive functions, but I have not been able to do it.
Somebody could help me?
thx

Comment: Have you? show us what you have tried

Comment: First i got an array like this:

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 18
        )

)
first key Idatribute, second ke auto, and the value its Id option value

Comment: i think i must walk atributes array foreach, and foreach option, walk next option of the next atribute, etc.

Comment: Thanks! 
I did not find that result in my search.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP side you can assign the multi-dimensional array simply like so:

```
$array = new Array();
```

adding an element:

```
$array['element'] = element;
```

where element can also be an array.

On SQL-Site however, you should not (but could) save the array as a string, delimited by some character. You rather should follow the relational approach and save the atomic values each  for it's own.

Comment: Thanks.
Sorry, my fault.
I got arrays without any problem, i'm looking for a recursive function so i can walk the array/s and get this strings (combinations of all option atributes.)

Comment: `foreach` walks an array